# Switch on / off Links on the page with one button: toggle() two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a working code for the two buttons:

HTML:

```
<button class="OFF-LINK">OFF</button>
<button class="ON-LINK">ON</button>

<div class="box">...<a></a>...<a></a>...</div>
<div class="box">...<a></a>...<a></a>...</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".OFF-LINK").click(function off() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box"); 
    var x; for (x = 0; x < box.length; x++) 
    {box[x].innerHTML = box[x].innerHTML.replace( /href/ig,'hren');}
}); ///links stop working

$(".ON-LINK").click(function on() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box"); 
    var y; for (y = 0; y < box.length; y++) 
    {box[y].innerHTML = box[y].innerHTML.replace( /hren/ig,'href');}
}); ///links work again
```

How can I combine this two functions, to toggle them with one button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by checking the returned match from `RegEx` pattern inside `.replace()` and swap it as per the below snippet

```js
function toggleLinks() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box"); 
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < box.length; x++) {
      box[x].innerHTML = box[x].innerHTML.replace(/hre(f|n)/gi,
          g1 => {return (g1=="href") ? "hren" : "href"});  
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleLinks()">Toggle Links</button>

<div class="box">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" >yahoo</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"> stackoverflow</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.github.com" >github</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I put some text in so you could see the changes

```js
$(".OFF-LINK,.ON-LINK").on('click', function() {
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  var x;
  for (x = 0; x < box.length; x++) {
    box[x].innerHTML = $(this).is('.OFF-LINK') ? box[x].innerHTML.replace(/href/ig, 'hren') : box[x].innerHTML.replace(/hren/ig, 'href');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="OFF-LINK">OFF</button>
<button class="ON-LINK">ON</button>

<div class="box">...
  <a>href</a>...
  <a>X</a>...
</div>
<div class="box">...
  <a>href</a>...
  <a>Y</a>...
</div>
```

How can I combine this two functions, to toggle them with one button?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to toggle the class on the button between `on-link` and `off-link`, and call the appropriate function afterwards? If so:

```
<button class="button off-link">Off</button>

$('body').on('click', '.button', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('off-link on-link');
  if ($(this).hasClass('off-link')) {
    $(this).innerHTML('Off');
    // Do your 'off-link' code here
  } else {
    $(this).innerHTML('On');
    // Do your 'on-link' code here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's bad practice to replace all innerHTML, just to change a little detail. If you need to toggle links, would be better to find the required links and work only with their attributes:

```js
$('.box a').each(function(){
  var link = $(this).attr("href");
  $(this).attr("data-link", link);
  // saving each link in data-attribute
});

$('#toggle').on('click', function toggler(){
  let on = toggler.on = !toggler.on; // (*1)
  
  $('.box a').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("data-link");
    
    $(this)[ on ? "removeAttr" : "attr" ]( "href", link ); // (*2)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">Toggle Links</button>

<div class="box">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
</div>
```

**(*1)** `let on = toggler.on = !toggler.on;` — each function is an object. You can work with it's name just like with common objects - setting him new properties or methods. I could declare a variable `let on = true;` out of the function, but decided to make everything inside. `!` — it's the boolean "NOT": transforms `false` → `true` and vice versa. So, when you click the button, `toggler.on` is undefined (false), `!` will become `true` and assign to itself (`toggler.on = !toggler.on;`) → the same value will be assigned to variable `on`.

At the next click, property `toggler.on` already will keep the `true` value, and become `!true → false`, and so on.

**(*2)** `$(this)[ on ? "removeAttr" : "attr" ]( "href", link );`

• *Ternary operator*, general form: `(boolean expression) ? (return this value if true) : (else)`

In this example, expression will return a "removeAttr" string, if `on === true`, and "attr" otherwise.

• *Bracket notation*. Mostly we use the *dot notation*, because it's shorter. Example, `elem.innerHTML` may be written as `elem["innerHTML"]`. Here I used a ternary expression, to pick the required method. Translation into if-else:

```
if( on ){
  $(this).removeAttr("href")
} else {
  var link = $(this).attr("data-link");
  $(this).attr("href", link );
}
```

And the same code without jQ:

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.box a');
for( let i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ){
  links[i].dataset.link = links[i].getAttribute("href");
}

let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
toggle.addEventListener('click', function toggler(){
  let on = toggler.on = !toggler.on;
  
  for( let i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ){
    let link = links[i].dataset.link;
    links[i][ on ? "removeAttribute" : "setAttribute"]("href", link);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Toggle Links</button>

<div class="box">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
</div>
```